# How to extract paragraph content and mark the text embedded to a link using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

Given a paragraph on a Wikipedia page (i.e. [Lana Del Ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lana_Del_Rey)) using `BeautifulSoup` I need to extract the text from the paragraph and mark the word or set of words that have enclosed a link.

For example, consider the first sentences of the first paragraph:

> Elizabeth Woolridge Grant (born June 21, 1985), known professionally
> as Lana Del Rey, is an American singer and songwriter. Her music is
> noted for its cinematic quality and exploration of tragic romance,
> [glamour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glamour_(presentation)), and [melancholia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melancholia), containing references to contemporary [pop
> culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popular_culture) and [1950s–1960s Americana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1945%E2%80%931960_in_Western_fashion).

I need to have it in this format:

> Elizabeth Woolridge Grant (born June 21, 1985), known professionally
> as Lana Del Rey, is an American singer and songwriter. Her music is
> noted for its cinematic quality and exploration of tragic romance,
> START_A glamour END_A, and START_A melancholia END_A, containing references to contemporary START_A pop
> culture END_A and START_A 1950s–1960s Americana END_A.

Until now I could extract either one paragraph or link separately using something like this:

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lana_Del_Rey").read())

 for tag in soup.select('p a[href]'):
     if tag['href'].startswith('/wiki/'):
         text = tag.text.strip()
         print(text)

for tag in soup.select('p'):
        text = tag.text.strip()
        print(text)
```

Is it possible to extract the text of the paragraph

tag and identify which words have a link attached to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `replaceWith()` to convert the `<a>` and its text to your expected output:

```
a.replaceWith('START_A '+a.text+' END_A')
```

##### Example

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lana_Del_Rey").read())

for tag in soup.select('p'):
    for a in tag.select('a'):
        a.replaceWith('START_A '+a.text+' END_A')
    print(tag.text)
```

###### Output

> Elizabeth Woolridge Grant (born June 21, 1985), known professionally
> as Lana Del Rey, is an American singer and songwriter. Her music is
> noted for its cinematic quality and exploration of tragic romance,
> START_A glamour END_A, and START_A melancholia END_A, containing
> references to contemporary START_A pop culture END_A and START_A 1950s
> END_A–START_A 1960s END_A START_A Americana END_A.START_A [1] END_A
> She is the recipient of START_A various accolades END_A, including two
> START_A Brit Awards END_A, two START_A MTV Europe Music Awards END_A,
> and a START_A Satellite Award END_A, in addition to nominations for
> six START_A Grammy Awards END_A and a START_A Golden Globe Award
> END_A.START_A [2] END_A START_A Variety END_A honored her at their
> START_A Hitmakers Awards END_A for being "one of the most influential
> singer-songwriters of the 21st century."START_A [3] END_ASTART_A [4]
> END_A

...